# Getting FaceBook Account Info with PHP After FB Authentication on Website

Tags: facebook

I'm reading through the Facebook Connect guide and have managed to get the authentication feature running, so that a user can register for a website via their FaceBook accounts.  On the registration page, users can enter their FB account info (if they're not alrady signed in) and after confirming the form is posted to a processing page.  On the processing page I want to grab their username and e-mail from their FaceBook account and enter it into a MySQL table using PHP, but I'm not sure how to get the info.  I tried var_dump($_POST) to see what was being passed, but I don't see the info I need.  How can I do this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In the [authentication document](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) there's a code sample that will walk you through the whole process and retrieve the user's info at the end:

```
<?php 

   $app_id = "YOUR_APP_ID";
   $app_secret = "YOUR_APP_SECRET";
   $my_url = "YOUR_URL";

   session_start();
   $code = $_REQUEST["code"];

   if(empty($code)) {
     $_SESSION['state'] = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE)); //CSRF protection
     $dialog_url = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" 
       . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url) . "&state="
       . $_SESSION['state'];

     echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $dialog_url . "'</script>");
   }

   if($_REQUEST['state'] == $_SESSION['state']) {
     $token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?"
       . "client_id=" . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url)
       . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret . "&code=" . $code;

     $response = file_get_contents($token_url);
     $params = null;
     parse_str($response, $params);

     $graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=" 
       . $params['access_token'];

     $user = json_decode(file_get_contents($graph_url));
     echo("Hello " . $user->name);
   }
   else {
     echo("The state does not match. You may be a victim of CSRF.");
   }

 ?>
```

**Important notes:**

1. Since this is not a canvas app you don't need to use Javascript redirection (I guess you already figured out the authentication part)
2. You may need to add the `scope` parameter and request extra [permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/) (email..etc) based on your requirements
3. After that, and with a valid `access_token` you will be able to retrieve the info you want:

   ```
   $graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=" 
          . $params['access_token'];
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Facebook PHP SDK? What you need to do first is to create the login URL:

```
$url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
            'canvas' => 0,
            'fbconnect' => 1,
            'req_perms' => 'read_stream, publish_stream, email' 
));
```

With this you are getting permission to read the email, stream and publish on their walls.

After you successfully logged, you can get all the user information using:

```
$userData = $facebook->api('/me'); // get logged user data
print_r($userData); // print everthing
```

and then manipulate the data using the $userData array.

If you have any doubts don't hesitate to ask.